# Debugging of match function in standared.php file in Magento

Tags: xdebug

I want to debug match function through PhpStorm that exists in

```
(/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php).
```

Now how would I know that my custom module is using this "match" function. After I run the debugging it opens the module I have configured in it with `"XDEBUG_SESSION_START=15967"` and shows in phpstorm like this

waiting for incoming connection with ide key `'15967'`.